# Downgrade (use a lower-versioned library) with a binding redirect

Tags: c#, binding, assemblies

I'm using an older version of NHibernate (v3.0.0.1001) and I'm stuck to it because the new LINQ provider breaks quite a few of my queries (something I'll be trying to fix later).  I want to update a library that uses NHibernate v3.1.0.4000.

I've tried adding a binding redirect in the App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.4000" newVersion="3.0.0.1001"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But when I compile, I get:

`error CS1705: Assembly 'My3rdPartyDll, Version=0.5.0.170, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'`

Is it possible to use a binding redirect to point to a downgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `probing` Element to specify a specific folder to find the dll, and then you can just past the dll into that folder.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="Assemblies"/> 
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

You can aslo specify a specific assembly to use which is what I think you are looking for.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WorkflowLibrary1" publicKeyToken="8afb6d596a769080" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="Version_1_0_0_0/WorkflowLibrary1.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

This [Link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/09/10/versioning-long-running-workfows.aspx) goes into more details about this.

Comment: Fixed "more details" link:

"Versioning long running workfows" by Maurice de Beijer
* [Part 1](https://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/2008/09/09/versioning-long-running-workfows/)
* [Part 2](https://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/2008/09/11/versioning-long-running-workflows-part-2/)
* [Part 3](https://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/2008/09/16/versioning-long-running-workfows-part-3/)
* [Part 4](https://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/2008/09/22/versioning-long-running-workflows-part-4/)