# bindingRedirect from app.config doesnt update exe.config on build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application, app-config

Why isnt the below bindingRedirect updating my exe.config file to the same version?  It keeps updating to the most recent?

**app.config**

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

**Application.exe.config**

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problem with versions, try this, unless your latest version is 4.0.0.0. If your latest version is 4.2.0.0  then I think you should use the latest version.

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: If I use the latest version I run into the dreaded "Version not found" bug which has been ongoing for a couple of years with Microsoft now.  Ill try the downgrade of the oldVersion and see what happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626874/downgrade-use-a-lower-versioned-library-with-a-binding-redirect